# Using a function in a loop in Python

Tags: python, mysql, loops

My aim is to get the last price from a histoy table (History_price) and inject it in a parameter table (param_forex).
I have defined the following function:

```
    mycursor.execute(f"UPDATE `param_forex` SET `Rate` = %s, `Update_Time` = CURRENT_TIME() WHERE `param_forex`.`Ticker` LIKE %s", 
                     (Rate, Ticker))
    mydb.commit()
    mycursor.close
```

The function works on its own. It simply fills a table with new prices on some particular lines.
Now I try to incorporate it in my loop. It's actually a double loop because of how mycursor works in mysql.connector

```
def fillpricetable_assetid() :
        for x in  ['EURUSD','EURJPY','EURGBP']:
            mycursor.execute(f"SELECT `Price` FROM `History_price` WHERE `Ticker` LIKE '{x}' ORDER BY `History_price`.`Time` DESC LIMIT 1")
            for y in mycursor:
                updateForexdb(x.lower(),y[0])
```

And it does not work anymore...
I get

```
  File "c:\...\library_import.py", line 116, in <module>
    fillpricetable_assetid()
  File "c:\...\library_import.py", line 89, in fillpricetable_assetid
    updateForexdb(x.lower(),y[0])
NameError: name 'updateForexdb' is not defined
```

How is that possible, when I have just defined it above??

Comment: We are lacking some information, like, are you using oop? is it in a class? in which order have you defined the function?

Comment: Where is `updateForexdb` defined?

Comment: updateForexdb was defined further down in the same file. I have interverted and now it works fine. I have always used functions defined further down and it has always worked. I don't understand why, in this instance, the order in which they are placed makes a difference...

Comment: order always make a difference if you are not in a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running multiple queries in a loop, why not just join the tables?

MySQL (any version):

```sql
UPDATE param_forex pf
JOIN History_price hp ON pf.Ticker = hp.Ticker
JOIN (
    SELECT Ticker, MAX(Time) AS max_time
    FROM History_price
    WHERE Ticker IN (?, ?, ?)
    GROUP BY Ticker
) hp_max ON hp.Ticker = hp_max.Ticker AND hp.Time = hp_max.max_time
SET pf.Rate = hp.Price, pf.Update_Time = NOW();
```

MySQL (>= 8.0):

```sql
UPDATE param_forex pf
JOIN (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY Time DESC) rn
    FROM History_price
    WHERE Ticker IN (?, ?, ?)
    -- interval within which you know you have latest price
    AND Time > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
) hp ON pf.Ticker = hp.Ticker AND hp.rn = 1
SET pf.Rate = hp.Price, pf.Update_Time = NOW();
```

Or, even better, don't store the redundant xrate values in `param_forex` and just access directly from `History_price`. Make sure you have an index on `(Ticker, Time)`.

Comment: I love the MySQL (any version) , thanks !
pf.Ticker is lower and hp.Ticker is cappitals. How do I take that into account ?

Comment: You could explicitly set the collation for the join with something like - `ON pf.Ticker COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci = hp.Ticker COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. What is your current charset/collation for the `Ticker` columns? You don't need to do anything if the collation is already case-insensitive.

Comment: Or `ON UPPER(pf.Ticker) = hp.Ticker`.

Comment: Thank you very much  @user1191247. I need to brush up my mysql skills...
Can you please help on my other post with a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have interverted the order and now it works fine.